# slapd not launching

Tags: macos, ldap, osx-snow-leopard, openldap

I have a slight problem with the openldap server installed with Mac OS X 10.6.8 (regular, not server). When I launch  `slapd` in a terminal, it stops itself after 1 or 2 seconds... I just have the time to see its process... It doesn't seem to crash, because when I specify a log file in the configuration, the log is created, but empty.

However, when I launch it with the debug option, for example `-d 1`,it doesn't fork and stays in the terminal (that's the documented behavior) and it runs normally. I can connect, and so on... Meaning, I presume, that's not a config problem.

Is there something stupid I've forgotten? (btw, I've repaired the authorizations, just in case, but that doesn't change the problem...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean you have to ask it here - http://serverfault.com

Comment: Ok, but I thought, here was also valid. I hope my bounty will motivate some here, even if I'm off topic...

Comment: I don't know if bounty motivates anyone, but you should figure out why the hell your process exists. Enable core dumps, check its logs (syslog?). Daemons don't exit for no good reason. Use ptrace/strace after all. I mean, really. No psychics here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already looked in the syslogs : nothing. No core dumps either. And the `dtruss` (os x `strace` equivalent) shows nothing weird... I really am stuck, and as I don't believe (yet) in black magic, there should be an explanation... I did it on an iMac and on a MacBookPro, and I have the same behavior...